# Passing button value from view to controller aspnet 5

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building a aspnet mvc6 application where I want to pass values from View to controller. My view has multiple buttons having IDs and I want to pass the ID of the button which is clicked to my controller using my viewmodel.

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private SampleDbContext _context;
    private HomeViewModel _viewmodel;

    public HomeController(SampleDbContext context, HomeViewModel model)
    {
        _viewmodel = model;
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _viewmodel.model = _context.MyModel.ToList();
        return View(_viewmodel);
    }

    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        var x = _viewmodel.buttonID; 
        return View();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class HomeViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<MyModel> model { get; set; }
        public int buttonID { get; set; }
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.HomeViewModel
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model.model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test">
                        <button value="Add"/>
                  </form> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

What should be done in the view such that I can set the value of '`buttonID`' of the `viewmodel` so that it is available in the controller?

Comment: use form inside your view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your form as:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test">
    <button value="Add" name="buttonName"/>
</form>
```

view model:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MyModel> model { get; set; }
    public string buttonName { get; set; }
}
```

and controller:

```
public ActionResult Test(HomeViewModel model) {
    if(model.buttonName == "Add") 
    ....
}
```

Comment: what will have to be done if we want to pass any custom object if there is no button?

Comment: @Ross What do you mean by "custom object"?

Comment: i mean the model which is present in the viewmodel. For enample there is a list of objects being passed to the model and I want to return one of them back to the controller

Comment: @Ross You can use for example hidden fields. Then your model should contain a property named after this field. If you have `<input name="HiddenField" type="hidden"/>` placed in your view, then your model should have the property `string HiddenField { get; set; }`

Comment: yeah that works. But one thing I noticed is that when I use `<input>` I am able to pass strings but it doesnt work for user defined types. For exmaple `public string field{get; set;}` works but `public MyType field{get; set;}` doesn't work

Comment: @Ross You can read about custom model binders, for example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an input field that will contain the data you want to send.

add this:

```
 <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test">
   <input asp-for="buttonID" value="yourButtonID" type="hidden"/>
   <button value="Add"/>
 </form>
```