# How can i check if button was clicked in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When i select button 1 nothing was showed,I need some message or with tempData so when i click button to show me message like this code below, but didn't show me nothing.
Here is my code in view and controler

view

```
 <button class="btn btn-default" value="selectUser" name="button" asp-action="check"
 >Select</button>
 <button class="btn btn-default" value="deselectuser" name="button" asp-action="check" 
 >Deselect</button>
```

And controler

```
 public ActionResult check(string button)
    {
        if(button == "selectUser")
        {
            TempData["Test"] = "First Clicked";
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Test"] = "Second Clicked";
        }
        return RedirectToAction("");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't see.

Comment: The `asp-action` in your HTML you've shown makes me think you're using ASP.NET Core MVC, not ASP.NET MVC. Which are you using? Is your question tagged appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

The names are the same, they should not be. It looks like you are trying to match on value, not name.

Your question was the first answer on google, right here on the stack.
[Passing button value from view to controller aspnet 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100619/passing-button-value-from-view-to-controller-aspnet-5)

The gist is that you need to pass a model, and use the button name from the model.